# Evaluating Semi-supervised Learning

Tags: hypothesis-testing, model-evaluation, validation, semi-supervised-learning

Is there a standard procedure to evaluate a semi-supervised learning algorithm?

Say if I have a set of labelled data (500 spam & 500 non-spam), and a set of 50,000 unlabelled data. Theoretically, I am going to use the labelled dataset to train a model, and classify the 50,000 unlabelled data.

However, how can I evaluate this model?

One of the ways which I can think of is to split the labelled data into specific proportion, say 90:10, and use 90% of the data to train the unsupervised model, and classify the 50,000 unlabelled data + 10% of labelled data. I can then evaluate the model based on the result from the 10% labelled data. Does it sound plausible?

Comment: The principle sounds feasible. However, in your context: how far would you trust an evaluation that is based on only 100 labelled cases? That depends on how many outliers, special cases, etc you have and how precise you need the evaluation to be. Side note: This site is called CrossValidated. Have you considered crossvalidation for the supervised part?

Comment: @Bernhard, exactly, I would also think that evaluation based on the 10% labelled cases are questionable. Cross validation is definitely possible, where if I perform a 10 fold CV, then I will be able to evaluate the whole labelled data.